# How to make jTable programatically behave AS IF it was focussed and received a KeyReleased

Tags: events, keyboard, jtable

I have a jFrame with many elements, including a jTable in a JScrollPane. The table responds ok to the keyboard when it's focused, but I would like it to react the same way to UP, DOWN etc. even when it's NOT focused, i.e. when some other element in the frame has focus.

I manage to catch the keyboard event from whatever element is focused, all I need now is to pass that event to the table. I thought that with evt being the KeyReleased event, doing

TheTable.dispatchEvent(evt)

or perhaps

TheScrollPane.dispatchEvent(evt)

would do the job, but neither works: the table doesn't react in any way. What do I do wrong?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Got it (i.e. SOLUTION below):

jTable (or JScrollPane) does NOT respond to Key**Released** events - but it DOES react to Key**Pressed**.

Catching KeyPressed events on the other elements in the frame and passing them to the table with

TheTable.dispatchEvent(evt)

actually does the job. Who would have guessed?